# Back propagation matrix shape error using Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, backpropagation, matrix

I  wanna implement the back-propagation algorithm in python with the next code

```
class MLP(object):
   def __init__(self, num_inputs=3, hidden_layers=[3, 3], num_outputs=2):
      self.num_inputs = num_inputs
      self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers
      self.num_outputs = num_outputs

        
      layers = [num_inputs] + hidden_layers + [num_outputs]

      weights = []
      bias = []
      for i in range(len(layers) - 1):
         w = np.random.rand(layers[i], layers[i + 1])
         b=np.random.randn(layers[i+1]).reshape(1, layers[i+1])  
         weights.append(w)
         bias.append(b)
      self.weights = weights
      self.bias = bias

      activations = []
      for i in range(len(layers)):
         a = np.zeros(layers[i])
         activations.append(a)
      self.activations = activations

      dW=[]
      db=[]
      for i in range(len(layers)-1):
         derW=np.zeros((layers[i], layers[i+1]))
         derb=np.zeros((layers[i+1])).reshape(1, layers[i+1])
         dW.append(derW)  
         db.append(derb)
      self.dW=dW  
      self.db=db


   def forward_propagate(self, inputs):
     activations = inputs
     
     self.activations[0] = activations
     for i, w in enumerate(self.weights):
        activations = self._sigmoid((np.matmul(activations, w)+self.bias[i))
         self.activations[i+1] = activations.T
     return activations

   def back_propagate(self,error):
      for i in reversed(range(len(self.dW))):
         activations=self.activations[i+1]
         delta = np.multiply(self._sigmoid(activations),error)
         print("This is delta: {} ".format(delta))
         current_activations=self.activations[i]
         current_activations = current_activations.reshape(current_activations.shape[0],-1)
         print("This is the current activations: {} ".format(current_activations))
         self.dW[i] = 1/delta.shape[0]*np.dot(current_activations,delta)

   def train(self, inputs, targets, epochs, learning_rate):
     for i in range(epochs):
       sum_errors = 0
       for j, input in enumerate(inputs):
         target = targets[j]
         output = self.forward_propagate(input)

         error = target - output
         self.back_propagate(error)

   def _sigmoid(self, x):
     y = 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
     return y
```

So I created the next dummy data in order to verify everything is correct

```
items = np.array([[random()/2 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(1000)])
targets = np.array([[i[0] + i[1]] for i in items])
    
mlp = MLP(2, [5], 1)
    
mlp.train(items, targets, 2, 0.1)
```

but when I run the code I have the next error

```
ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (5,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
```

I understand the error because when I printed the delta and current activations values I have the next ones:

```
This delta: [[-0.67139682]] 
This is the current activations: [[ 0.11432486]
 [-0.38246416]
 [-0.85207878]
 [ 0.73210993]
 [ 0.76603196]] 
This is delta: [[-1.45663835]
 [-1.2793182 ]
 [-0.76875725]
 [-0.90048138]
 [-0.86253739]] 
This is the current activations: [[0.08248608]
 [0.12631125]]
```

So what I really want is that the current activation
`[[-0.67139682]]`
multiply with this delta value

```
[[0.08248608]
 [0.12631125]]
```

and this current activations

```
[[ 0.11432486]
 [-0.38246416]
 [-0.85207878]
 [ 0.73210993]
 [ 0.76603196]]
```

multiply with this delta value

```
[[-1.45663835]
 [-1.2793182 ]
 [-0.76875725]
 [-0.90048138]
 [-0.86253739]]
```

but I don't know how to do that. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should change:

```
self.dW[i] = 1/delta.shape[0]*np.dot(current_activations,delta)
```

to

```
self.dW[i] = 1/delta.shape[0]*np.dot(current_activations,delta.T)
```

in the back propagation function. This will help you to avoid the error.

Comment: but it is ok if in the forward propgate the activations are already transpose?